# Solution to a non linear system of equations

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

Does there exist an interval I such that this system of equations has no solution?

```
k1(b1-a1)+a1 = k2(b2-a2)+a2
k1(b1^2-a1^2)+a1^2 = k2(b2^2-a2^2)+a2^2
k1(b1^3-a1^3)+a1^3 = k2(b2^3-a2^3)+a2^3

none of a1,b1,a2,b2 are equal  
a1,b1,a2,b2 are on interval I  
K1 and K2 are members of the reals
```

A proof would be appreciated if such an interval can be found or a proof of why no such interval can exist.

Thanks

Comment: What are the variables, and what are the parameters?

Comment: E.g. one solution is $k_1=1$, $k_2=0$, $a_2=b_1$, $a_1$ and $b_2$ arbitrary.

Comment: Similarly for $k_1 = 0$, $k_2 = 1$, $a_1 = b_2$.  Also $a_1 = b_2$, $a_2 = b_1$, $k_1 + k_2 = 1$.

Comment: What is the context in which you found these equations ? It may help to know it ...

Comment: the initial problem is proving there exists or does not exist four points on the 3d curve <x,x^2,x^3> such that when straight lines are drawn between them the lines intersect

Comment: I have extended this question to proving these points exists or do not exist for any interval of the curve

Comment: I've set the equations up as a Vandermonde matrix [ax,bx][k1,k2]  The question is (?):  Does there exist an interval [I] such that for $\forall$ k1,k2 the above equations do not have a solution ax,bx $\in$I?    Or is the interval allowed to vary with k1,k2?   In any case, the solution seems to be analyzing the vector spaces of the Vandermonde matrix taken as a transform. The matrix is a little large for the margin of this comment.  I can put it up as part of a solution or elsewhere on the web.

Comment: In other words: is the I in question supposed to be independent of k1,k2 ?